# ValueError: Invalid tensors 'normalized_input_image_tensor' were found

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, tensorflow-ssd

OS: Ubuntu 18.04,
Tensorflow model:ssd_mobilenet_v2_quantized_300x300_coco_2019_01_03

I have retrained the ssd_mobilenet_v1_quantized_coco model using my own data. I have successfully generated the frozen_inference_graph.pb, using the script, "*export_inference_graph.py*." But when I ran the script, "*tflite_convert.py*," the error, "**ValueError: Invalid tensors 'normalized_input_image_tensor**' **were found**." broke out. The parameters of the script, "*tflite_convert.py*" is

```
 python tflite_convert.py \
--output_file="converted_quant_traffic_tflite/traffic_tflite_graph.tflite" \
--graph_def_file="traffic_inference_graph_lite/frozen_inference_graph.pb" \
--input_arrays='normalized_input_image_tensor' \
--inference_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 \
--output_arrays='TFLite_Detection_PostProcess','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:1','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:2','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:3' \
--mean_values=128 \
--std_dev_values=128 \
--input_shapes=1,300,300,3 \
--default_ranges_min=0 \
--default_ranges_max=6 \
--change_concat_input_ranges=false \
--allow_nudging_weights_to_use_fast_gemm_kernel=true \
--allow_custom_ops
```

Obviously, the **input_arrays** was not set correctly. Please advise me how to set the **input_arrays**.

Comment: Maybe try to generate frozen graph via `export_tflite_ssd_graph.py` file, instead of `export_inference_graph.py`? They are in the same directory and as I remember this one should be used for further `tflite` conversion.

Comment: @sebastoam-sz Thank you for your suggestion. It is working if I use export_tfilte_ssd_graph.  But I still do not understand why the export_inference is not working.

Comment: Might be that TFLite Conversion only supports [specific operations](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_compatibility) and `export_inference` uses some operations that are not supported. But that's just my guess.

Comment: @sebastoam-sz It sounds like. Thank you for the information.